# How to observe changes of all class members for an object in Swift (or ObjectiveC)?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a class something like

```
class Foo {
  var bar : Int = 0
  var baz : Boolean = false

  var updated_at : NSDate
}
```

I am fine with class being inherited from NSObject (if there are some Objective-C goodies which can be used).

I want to have some code which automatically updated `updated_at` each time when bar or baz are changed.

There is a obvious solution (to add `willSet` or `didSet`) for each member to update `updated_at`.

However, it will require to add `willSet` or `didSet` to **each** class member. As result, if there are 100 of them, I will need to have 100 copies of the code (which I really don't like)

I am looking for a way how can I write once piece of code (vs multiple copies) which will observe changes of all members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved in objective C using :

- (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffecting {
  return [NSSet setWithObject:@"bar", @"baz", nil];
  }

and then add custom setter for updated_at. Follow this link for detail.
https://www.objc.io/issues/7-foundation/key-value-coding-and-observing/

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to combine `bar` and `baz` into a tuple that triggers the update, and then add the `didSet` to that:

```
class Foo {

    var values: (bar: Int, baz: Bool) = (0, false) {

            didSet {
                self.updated_at = NSDate()
            }
        }

    var updated_at  = NSDate()
}
```

Access them like this:

```
let foo = Foo()
foo.values.bar = 10  // will trigger the didSet method
```

One advantage to this approach is that you can add other properties outside of the `values` tuple that won't trigger the update. For example, I don't think you want changes to `updated_at` to trigger a change to `updated_at`, so method that watched every single property wouldn't work - it would be watching the `updated_at` property too!

Comment: You are right, updated_at should be excluded. This is interesting approach. However, let me think about downsides.